# Turning on Wi-Fi on demand

Tags: wi-fi, standby

Is there a way to reconnect to Wi-Fi whenever an application accesses the network?

Background: I have a rooted e-book reader that runs Android 2.2 (Sony Reader PRS-T1). The system offers an option to automatically enter Wi-Fi standby mode when the connection is idle, which I like: This behavior saves a lot of battery juice when reading an e-book.

Some of the preinstalled apps know how to reconnect the Wi-Fi whenever they need network access. Unfortunately, conventional Android apps do not know how to do this and fail. For example, I have installed the Kindle for Android app, and it fails to sync reading positions unless I have manually re-enabled the the Wi-Fi before trying to do so.

Is there a method to leave Wi-Fi standby mode and reconnect to Wi-Fi whenever there is demand?

Answer (score 1):

Like everyone seems to be saying I too say that you can do this with [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en) and here's a small tutorial

In your profiles screen, click the + button and select application.

In the following screen that shows with the list of your installed apps, choose the app that you would wish to turn the WiFi on when opened.

Go back and you will be asked to create a new task. Create one and add the action WiFi and set it to on.

Now go back and long press on the task you created and click 'Add exit task' do the same thing as you did before but instead of setting it as on, set it to off.

So now whenever you open that app, the WiFi is turned on and at other times is off.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain, but I'd expect [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) to be able to do this.

Comment: Not that I know of, at least not out of the box. I have Tasker on my phone, and I cannot find an option to trigger a task when an app accesses the network. Maybe you're thinking of a specific Tasker or Locale plugin?

Comment: The behavior described in the question sounds to me like a custom WiFi standby solution - this wouldn't be something available in Tasker. What one could do, though, is have Tasker toggle WiFi on/off (perhaps with a short `wait` in between). That might kick it out of standby.

Comment: Sure, Tasker can kick wifi out of standby. The question is -- how can this be triggered on demand, automatically?

Comment: Easy to do if Wifi should always be active when certain apps run in the foreground (just select those apps as conditions for a profile). But if they simply "want to access" while in background, there's nothing I can think of.

Comment: I'm thinking of WeFi app, but it's probably not a good idea since it would be looking for a WiFi connection all the time.

Comment: WeFi app wouldn't do, it has a completely different job (checking for available Wifi networks close-by). The question is not about Wifi availibility -- but about the apps demand to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You wont find any app to do it. By default Wifi maintains the connection while consuming very less power. Power gets consumed only when data is exchanged.

Also, I am not sure which ROM you are using but most ROMs should contain something like "Wifi Sleep policy" to help you turnoff wifi when your phone enters sleep mode. If you cant find this option then you can try an app called Llama (similar to tasker) which allows you to control your wifi sleep policy based on location, time, profile, etc

Answer (score 0):

The only way of doing this would be [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en). This app allows you to set conditions for functions of the phone and apps. For example I'm using this to enable lock screen when I disconnect from my home WiFi and connect to 4G when I'm not connected to any WiFi. Give it a try.