# On-demand WiFi during sleep

Tags: wi-fi, 4.2-jelly-bean, standby, nexus-4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Turning on Wi-Fi on demand](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25635/turning-on-wi-fi-on-demand)

I can only find 3 options under `Settings->Wi-Fi->Advanced->Keep Wi-Fi on during sleep`:

- Always ((the default value))
- Only when plugged in
- Never (increases data usage)

I feel like there's missing a 4th option, "On-demand". I want it to use Wi-Fi when needed (if possible), but I don't necessarily want Wi-Fi enabled all the time. It feels like my battery life suffer when running with the "Always" option.

Is there a way for Android to use Wi-Fi on-demand when it's needed during sleep?

If relevant, I'm running stock Android 4.2.1 on an LG Nexus 4.

Comment: Have you compared your battery life with "Never" to battery life with "Always"? Typically it seems like the opposite has been true on my phones - disabling WiFi *increases* battery usage, possibly because the 3G/4G chip draws more power than the WiFi chip (and may require longer transfers since it's slower, thereby increasing awake time).

Comment: My wording was wrong, as I haven't done any "scientific" tests of this, so I guess the wording should be feel vs. noticed. My question still stands tho. Is there a way for on-demand, instead of having it always on? Seems wasteful.

Comment: And we had this question already a couple of days ago ([Turning on Wi-Fi on demand](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25635/turning-on-wi-fi-on-demand)): No, there's no way for "on demand".

Comment: How would you determine "on demand". If the phone is in sleep mode (eg the screen is off) how does it know that *you* want the wifi used for the current data request, and not 3G? If you've got background data switched on, then there will be a lot of data requests happening while your phone is asleep, with no way to know that you're actually "demanding" it?

Comment: @Izzy: That question is not about Wi-Fi during sleep tho. I'm talking about what happens when the phones screen is off. He seems to be talking about when the screen is on and he is not using Wi-Fi.

Comment: @GAThrawn: I'm not sure I follow you. I'm just looking for a way for Wi-Fi to be automatically switched on when the data requests are performed, and turned off when they are completed. If my phone is "demanding" it, then I am also demanding it, since I've installed whatever is on the phone doing the data requests.

Comment: @ohaal doesn't matter which way, there's no such thing as "on demand". We already had this in different combinations, e.g. Wifi should be enabled only when app X needs it. Sure you could play with JuiceDefender and the like for it -- but there's no real solution available to my knowledge.

Comment: rather than turning off wifi (which is usually more battery efficient than 3G), I'd think you'd probably benefit more from turning down the syncing frequency. You should be able to create a Tasker/Locale/Llama/AutomateIt profile to disable syncing or any data connection when sleeping, and only reenable it every x minutes for a short period or so.